# Getting "No such file or directory" even after using > /dev/null 2>&1 at the end of the command

Tags: linux, bash

I have written a script where it checks the PID of that JVM. If PID is not existing for that specific JVM, it will give exit status 2 and terminates the script. To check the PID, I do a cat of specific file which contains the PID. When there is no PID or no file which contains PID, it is throwing "No such file or directory" even after redirecting the output using > /dev/null 2>&1 at the end of the command.

I don't want the output displayed on the screen. If someone could help me on that would be really helpful.

**EDIT** this is the code snippet:

```
ONLINE=grep -ir "$HOSTNAME-"$VAR" is currently online" /home/logs/$GF_OWNER/$HOSTNAME-"$VAR"/$HOSTNAME-"$VAR".log | wc -l 
OFFLINE=0 
PID=cat /home/logs/$GF_OWNER/$HOSTNAME-"$VAR"/gemstart.pid
```

Comment: if you want help, better post the code you are using (only the part relevant to this question) ; then somebody might try to help... otherwise it is difficult to say what is going wrong

Comment: This is the code:                                           ONLINE=`grep -ir "$HOSTNAME-"$VAR" is currently online" /home/logs/$GF_OWNER/$HOSTNAME-"$VAR"/$HOSTNAME-"$VAR".log | wc -l` 
OFFLINE=0
PID=`cat /home/logs/$GF_OWNER/$HOSTNAME-"$VAR"/gemstart.pid`

Comment: Can you put it directly in your question, preferably as a code snippet ?

Comment: I still don't see the > /dev/null 2>&1 part in your code snippet...

Comment: Sorry! here it is:                                                              ONLINE=`grep -ir "$HOSTNAME-"$VAR" is currently online" /gem/logs/$GF_OWNER/$HOSTNAME-"$VAR"/$HOSTNAME-"$VAR".log | wc -l` > /dev/null 2>&1
OFFLINE=0
PID=`cat /gem/logs/$GF_OWNER/$HOSTNAME-"$VAR"/gemstart.pid` > /dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

It think you should try to test if your file exists before using cat/ls/whatever on it. For that, use the if/test structure :

```
if [ -e $PETH_TO_THE_FILE ]; then
   //processing here
else

fi
```

This way you won't have unnecessary output.